# How I can set program autostart to my second desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, autostart

In Lubuntu we have folder `/home/username/.config/autostart`. Its OK, but how I can autostart app on my "invisible" desktop and in fullscreen (like after pressing F11)?

Answer (score 1):

You Want to look into a program called devilspie. [Ubuntu-Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)

It is in the repos so a simple `sudo apt-get install devilspie` will do it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [desktop entry spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/), there don't appear to be any position-based properties in the [standard entry keys](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

If the specific application you're running accepts positional parameters though, you might be able to get it to work that way in the `Exec` entry.